# Basic OS X folders - folder structure regarding users

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, folders

I am logged in as user "vlado" on my MacBook running El Capitan. If I go and type `whoami` in Terminal, it says *vlado* too. So this is fine. But in my folder structure in hd/Users/vlado/Applications I don't see my Applications, which I can otherwise see through Finder. I have my applications no problem and I run them no problem, but the folder structure is confusing me. Shouldn't the applications go into my user's (vlado's) folder structure and not to hd/Applications?

Comment: Related - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199039/in-os-x-mavericks-yosemite-is-it-better-to-put-apps-in-applications-or-in-ap/199054#199054

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick answer....

Items in the `Applications` are system wide, not per user.  You can deny Users access to particular applications, but in general they are available to everyone.

The `User` folder holds items that are specific to each user and only available to each user individually and the superuser (root).

[Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/1139359/osxfolderstructure.html) has a good article that goes into this further

Also, OS X Daily had a nice summary table of the folder structure which should be helpful:

[image]